# Ввод ссылки без протокола - py requests

Tags: python, requests

Задача заключается в вводе ссылки для `requests` без протокола и без `://`.
Должны приниматься и после обрабатываться ссылки типа:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/
stackoverflow.com
http://cppstudio.com/
```

код:

```
import re, requests
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

url_input = str(input("Enter url: "))

url_checked = re.findall(r'regex here', url_input)[0]

response = requests.get(url_checked)

result = re.findall( r"\"(?:http[s]?://)([^:/\s\"]+)/?[^\"]*\"", response.text)

result.sort()

pt = PrettyTable(field_names = ["word", "counter"])
pt.add_rows(list(Counter(result).most_common()))
print(pt)
```

измененный код:

```
import re, requests, validators
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable

url_input = str(input("Enter url: ").strip())

validators.url(url_input)
if not validators.url(url_input):
    print("Entered link is not correct...")
    quit()

if not url_input.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
    try:
        response = requests.get("https://" + url_input)
    except:
        response = requests.get("http://"  + url_input)

result = re.findall( r"\"(?:http[s]?://)([^:/\s\"]+)/?[^\"]*\"", response.text)
result.sort()

pt = PrettyTable(field_names=["word", "counter"])
pt.add_rows(list(Counter(result).most_common()))
print(pt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не везде нужно использовать `regex`.

В `python` есть масса более понятных функций для работы со строками.

```
import re
import requests
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable


url_input = input("Enter url: ").strip()

if url_input.startswith('http://'):
    url_input = url_input[7:]
if url_input.startswith('https://'):
    url_input = url_input[8:]

try:
    response = requests.get("https://" + url_input)
except:
    response = requests.get("http://" + url_input)

result = re.findall( r"\"(?:http[s]?://)([^:/\s\"]+)/?[^\"]*\"", response.text)
result.sort()

pt = PrettyTable(field_names=["word", "counter"])
pt.add_rows(list(Counter(result).most_common()))

print(pt)
```

Comment: 1. Ваш код не работает. Выдает ошибку - ``Invalid URL 'stackoverflow.com/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://stackoverflow.com/?``` при том что ввел ```https://stackoverflow.com/```, пробовал ввести ```stackoverflow.com```, тоже не работает.

Comment: 2. В задаче сказано что requests.get должен работать как с ссылкой **с** протоколом, так и с ссылкой **без** протокола.

Comment: Поправил код. Попробуй теперь.

Comment: да. все заработало. большое спасибо

Comment: В коле я полагаю есть недочет, при котором если у ссылки протокол не secure, то все ломается. иными словами, у вас написано ‘https://’ + ..., а если у ссылки протокол ’http://’? ccpstudio.com выдало ошибку в requests (имеет протокол http)

Comment: О том использует сайт http или https мы можем узнать только постфактум. В коде это можно сделать с помощю try except. Try http, если exception то пробуем https.

Comment: пробовал, выдает ошибку

Comment: Покажи ошибку. И добавил изменения в коде ответа.

Comment: добавил в вопрос обновленный код, уже рабочий после дополнительных правок